# Capybara Evaluation times out when Debugging with RubyMine in Ruby 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara, rubymine

I use RubyMine, and since I've upgraded to Ruby 2.3.3, I can no longer evaluate Capybara methods in the RubyMine debugger. What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that Ruby 2.3 changed the default `open_timeout` from nil/0 to 60 (seconds). As a result, any evaluation attempts spawned a new thread which was not started because the debugger had frozen the process at the breakpoint.

The solution was to:

- Subclass `Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default` and override the `open_timeout` property on the `Net::HTTP` object being spawned.
- Change the Capybara `javascript_driver` so it used an instance of `Capybara::Selenium::Driver` that used the new subclass as its `http_client` option.

Details in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/richseviora/24622a90b4a2993cf3db9075643b4b94).